# Open Recycle Bin folder in Explorer

Tags: java

I use

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Folder"));
```

top open a specific folder in the Windows explorer. How can I open the Windows trash folder by using the Desktop.getDesktop().open method?
I have figured out that executing

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\$Recycle.bin"));
```

opens the Recycle Bin of Drive C:\ but if the Recycle Bin contains deleted objects from D:\ they don't show up. I want to open the "global" Recycle Bin containg deleted objects from all drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution will run a command line command and will open the global recycle bin

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start shell:RecycleBinFolder");
    p.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
  catch (IOException e) {}
```